# Find all composition factors of a group of order $780$ that is not solvable.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

I've seen this problem on [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/%7Ebeachy/abstract_algebra_3ed/review/review.pdf) and I'm having a hard time understanding the solution:

> Let $G$ be a group of order $780 = 2^2
> \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 13$. Assume that $G$ is not solvable. What are the composition factors of $G$? (Assume that the only nonabelian simple group of order $\le 60$ is the
> alternating group $A_5$.)

The solution states:

> The Sylow $13$-subgroup $N$ is normal, since $1$ is the only divisor of $60$ that is $\equiv
> 1 \pmod{13}$. Using the fact that the smallest simple nonabelian group has order $60$, we see that the factor $G/N$ must be simple, since otherwise each composition factor would be abelian and $G$ would be solvable. Thus the composition factors are $\Bbb Z_{13}$ and $A_5$.

What I don't understand is why does $G/N$ not being simple imply that all composition factors are abelian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $780 = 13 \cdot 60 = 13 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

NB: this explains the argument "$N$ is normal, since $1$ is the only divisor of $60$ that is $≡ 1$ (mod $13$)", using Sylow's theorem(s).

Assuming $G$ has order $780$, the order of $G/N$ is $60$.

Now, assume $G/N$ isn't simple. Then, its composition factors would haver order $<60$, hence would be abelian. Then, look at a composition series
$$
\{1\} = M_0 \triangleleft M_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft M_k = G/N
$$ of $G/N$. Setting $N_i = \{g\in G: gN \in M_i\}$, we would get a composition series
$$
\{1\} \triangleleft N_0 \triangleleft N_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft N_k = G/N
$$
of $G$, where $N_0 = N$ would be abelian (cyclic of order $13$) and each $N_{i+1}/N_i$ would be isomorphic to $M_{i+1}/M_i$, hence abelian.

Comment: Typo in the last composition series: it should be $=G$, right?